# What mathematical equation can be used to represent the output of this differential amp circuit?

Tags: operational-amplifier, differential, math

My lecturer has gave my class a number of circuits to analysis and currently I'm having trouble with the following circuit:
[image]

I am familiar with how to calculate an equation for the standard differential amp but I'm struggling with this one because of the extra resistor (R1) and the one voltage source (which would make me assume that the output would be 0). It can be assumed R1 = R2 and R3 = R4, how does one derive a calculation for this?

Comment: Redraw the circuit; solving for V+ should be straightforward, then you've nearly got a an inverting topology with a minor change on the input and an offset on V+.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must do the hard work.Most of us only want to show the direction.

At first notice: The +input of the opamp get its voltage V+ from a voltage divider. V+ = V * R2/(R4+R2). For that we assume the opamp to be ideal - no input current!

Assuming this circuit stable and to be in balance, the -input of the opamp must also have the same voltage V+

Write the output voltage as Uo. You get a massive node voltage equation by setting the sum of the currants that go out from -input to be zero.

Those currents are V+/R1 , ((V+) - V)/R3 and ((V+)-Uo)/R5

Happy equation writing and solving.

ADDENDUM: No equation solving is needed, if one assumes there be 2 separate voltage sources =V. The first V, say V1 , is connected to R1, R3 and GND. The other, say V2, is connected to R2, R4 and GND. You can make the Uout as superposition. First part is from V1 (=V) through an invering amplifier. V2 is kept as zero. The second part is from V2 through non-inverting amplifier, V1 is kept as zero (=wire) when calculating. Add the parts.

Comment: Thank you! My main issue was to do with the currents. I can work it out from here

Answer (score 1):

As a plan of attack, I would say:

1. Calculate \$V_+\$, which is independent of the rest of the circuit.
2. By the ideal op amp rules, \$V_-\$ must be equal to \$V_+\$.
3. (a) Write a KCL equation for the \$V_-\$ node, or...
4. (b) Simplify the circuit by finding the Thevenin equivalent of V, R1, and R3 from the perspective of the \$V_-\$ node.